# Is there a way to override GitHub context variables in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I know that currently [this can't be done](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#naming-conventions-for-environment-variables) , I'm trying to run some integration tests on my action that requires an issue event to be passed, I have a sample json with the event data and I would like to override both:

```
GITHUB_EVENT_NAME
GITHUB_EVENT_PATH
```

So my action grabs the right event and the sample info. Is there a workaround or a better way to approach this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester46.yml) with this [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7438424255?check_suite_focus=true) if you want to have a look. I tried to override a GitHub context variable, but I could only add a different value as an env variable (`${{ env.GITHUB_EVENT_NAME }}`). Would that be an alternative / workaround to your problem?